# Low latency keyboards - are they for real?

Tags: usb, keyboard, protocol, latency

Having just seen some commercial or other I just realized there could be such a thing as a high-latency keyboard—as compared to a low-latency keyboard. If so, then maybe a low-latency one could be yet another good thing to make all my coding experiences that tiny bit more wonderful.

But I am having a lot of trouble finding the *research* about this, as opposed to marketing! Where is some authoritative or at least useful information?

How bad is the 'standard' keyboard latency? Are we talking milliseconds? Tens of milliseconds?

What are the technology limitations involved in the software/hardware protocols [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port), USB, USB 2.0, USB channels, interrupts, etc.? What has been published?

Comment: @Mark: As always, game players will likely care about this.

Comment: @Mark: All the time. Bluetooth and RF Keyboards have notorious lag. Perhaps not noticeable to most people, but for myself and other hardcore FPS players, it's a night and day difference.

Comment: @Mark: I get this just typing on plenty of keyboards, particularly wireless

Comment: To answer your offtopic question: keyboard latency is less with hardware, and more with the resolution of the clock. I use to work with keystroke dynamics for 2nd auth factor, and we measured key latency. This is a pretty decent paper on it: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2F~ksk%2FKillourhyMaxion08b.pdf&ei=nlwcTMX7ENOCnQfJk93tDQ&usg=AFQjCNFVqpiFVPkZSTvJ1M2u1Mrq1Sdytg&sig2=olqy5lr4UR19F0P2GiChhg

Comment: And, if you're interested. Looking up information on Keystroke Dynamics--using unique typing rhythms to provide 2nd factor authentication. There is gobs of information regarding keyboard timings. Interestingly enough IE's javascript timing resolution is bad!

Comment: @Alan: Provided you are not using JavaScript in IE, higher resolution clocks are available. The limit on the USB polling rate can't be solved by software.

Comment: I've used a wireless mouse and keyboard at home (use wired keyboard at work) for ages and have never noticed a difference. I don't know, I guess I just don't type fast enough for the speed of light to be a bottleneck.

And if you're worried about bandwidth rather than latency, Bluetooth 2.0 has a throughput rate of 3Mbit/sec., which is over 390,000 bytes/sec. And it takes far less than one byte to transfer a single keypress. The plastic keys would melt before you ran into a bottleneck from RF or Bluetooth keyboard connections.

Comment: And just to clarify, I do believe there are latency differences between keyboards. But I'm more keen on Alan's explanation based on clock resolution rather than connection quality.

But even still, _low latency keyboards_ sound like a scam. Even for a gamer, the clock resolutions of the average cheapo keyboard is high enough that you'd be better off optimizing the feel and ergonomics of the keys themselves if you're a gamer worried about "keypress latency". Decreasing the resistance and push distance would probably make more sense than buying a "low-latency" keyboard.

Comment: This guy measured latency on different keyboards: https://danluu.com/keyboard-latency/

Answer (score 4):

For USB keyboards, the latency is going to be bounded by the USB polling rate. USB only transfers data from an end device when the host actively polls it—there isn't any concept of exception sends.

USB devices can specify their polling rate (for "interrupt" endpoints, not for bulk or control endpoints). In general, most keyboards and mice will have a latency around 4 ms, though it can be higher. By setting the descriptor to a small value (1 ms for full speed, 125 µs for high speed) you can improve the USB latency. You can [have a look at the endpoint descriptor field layout](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.htm#EndpointDescriptors).

Answer (score 2):

There is some in-depth analysis of latency when typing into an editor. See *[Typing with pleasure, 2.1 Input latency](https://pavelfatin.com/typing-with-pleasure/#input-latency)*.

There is some latency from the keyboard scanning, some from USB, but then also other factors, like the OS input processing, application speed and screen rendering.

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) comes out fastest, but you need to turn off [Aero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) on Windows, and turn off composting rendering on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), to reduce latency.

Here is the relevant part about latency from the keyboard itself:

> Keyboard scan
>
> Typical keyboard contains more than 100 keys, which is quite a lot. To minimize the number of wires and control processor inputs, key switches are usually connected in a matrix circuit, so that rows and columns of wires cross. That’s how it’s possible to reduce the number of wires and inputs from x * y to x + y (for example, to 22 instead of 121). The drawback of such an approach is that control processor cannot read the state of all the keys simultaneously — it has to scan switches repeatedly, with some constant frequency, which results in some latency. Typical matrix scan rate is 1000 Hz, so maximum scan-related latency is 1 ms (average delay is 0.5 ms).

Comment: This is a pure software test, while OP is asking about keyboards (hardware).

Comment: That is addressed in the post.  I've now added the relevent excerpt to make it more relevent to the question without having to open the article.